# How to avoid multiple installation/repair of same product using MSI Installer

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-installer, gpo

I want to make an **MSI installer** for my application and I also need to remotely deploy this application via active directory software deployment. I also need to make sure that this application is not installed multiple times and should not allow any repair or modification. To ensure this thing I have made **ARPNOREPAIR=1** in my installer. This works fine if I try to install multiple instances manually or even silently. But I am facing problem when I am doing it using active directory. It always allow multiple installation which leads to a corrupt installation state. I want to is there any way I can make sure that multiple instances of the applications are not installed even if the versions are different.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really mean multiple instances?  That's an advanced authoring scenario that takes a while to pull off.  What is your ALLUSERS property set to?  I'm guessing you mean to say that it's installing in the per-user context over and over for different profiles.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to block all versions of a .msi package from being installed is to use the information provided by the `UpgradeCode`. You can find out if other versions of the related packages by adding the following (using WiX toolset syntax):

```
<Upgrade Id='PUT-UPGRADE-CODE-HERE'>
   <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect='yes' Property='FOUND_RELATED_PACAKGE' />
</Upgrade>
```

That will set a Property named `FOUND_RELATED_PACKAGE` to the list of `ProductCodes` from already installed packages. Then you could block the install like so (using WiX toolset syntax):

```
<Condition Message='Another version of [ProductName] is already installed.">
    Installed OR NOT FOUND_RELATED_PACAKGE
</Condition>
```

Finally, it is very dangerous to block repair of an .msi package. There are many situations (including minor upgrade and patching) that depend on repair working for a package. It'd be much better to make your installation package resilient to repair since it is so fundamental to how things work.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Rob, I have put all these conditions but my problem is that these checks are not working when I am installing this application using active directory group policy.